# Paste option in Word/Power point

Tags: ms-word, office365, powerpoint, copy-paste

When I copy anything from any web and I wanted to paste in word/power point, the paste option shows and works perfectly. When I copy a snippet of a code from Notepad++, sublime, or even an online editor, the paste options in word/power point disappears, and the "keep text only" option remains.
I've uninstalled and installed office, notepad, downgrade etc.. nothing works.
I've even checked the add-ins removal from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/troubleshoot/word/issues-when-start-or-use-word) also nothing works.
Needless to say the "Show paste options" in Advanced/options is ticked in.
I'd really appreciate any help, as I'm trying to copy/paste large chunks of code into a documentation work, and having to adjust every snippet manually is a burden.
Thank you!

Comment: This is imho not a problem of the Office paste options. Code editors typically just put plain text without formatting information into the clipboard on "Copy", so there is technically no option to "Paste" formatted and if there is just one option available - plain text - there is no point for Office to show a paste options dialog.

Comment: To add a bit to @Halfix's comment:  PowerPoint (and pretty much any other program that allows Paste Special) will only show you options to paste whatever formats are on the clipboard and that it recognizes. Since text editors only put text on the clipboard, that's the only option you get.

Comment: Both Halfix and @SteveRindsberg  are all right. You can paste the from any website, it should either copy text on a web page itself copies its formatted information or the code section of that page have an option(button or link facility, etc.) to copy the code, which naturally comes with information on the format of the code. You can reference my answer below.THANKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know the Notepad++ should be installed the plugins named **NppExport** to do **Copy RTF to clipboard** so that the copied format will be applied in MS Word. It's NOT directly copied from the Notepad++ to paste to Word. Just like the below pic showing. That is, the problem is not in MS Word side.

[image]

If this is practical for you, then you can open the other code you want to copy and format in NotePad++, or paste it into Notepad++ and perform the above steps, and then paste it into MS Word or PowerPoint.

Comment: Great suggestion. Thanks!  I wasn't aware of this plug-in for NPP.